# How can I pass an folder path to an custom action ExeCommand

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.9

We have the following folder structure in our wix declaration:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="$(var.ProgramFilesFolder)">
        <Directory Id="ManufacturerFolder" Name="$(var.Manufacturer)">
          <Directory Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Name="$(var.AppFolderName)">

            // further folders or files

          </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Target: We want to delete the APPLICATIONFOLDER on an uninstall. `RemoveFolderEx` and `RemoveFolder` will not work for this task, so we need to use a CustomAction. The CustomAction:

```
<CustomAction Directory="ManufacturerFolder" ExeCommand='/c rmdir /S /Q "[APPLICATIONFOLDER]"' Id="RemoveAppFolder" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" Return="ignore"/>
```

This custom action deletes nothing. What is the correct declaration?

Comment: And what is in the log of the custom action?

Answer (score 0):

Why Don't you do it like this?
It must work on uninstall. 
For example just place it in component where you have shortcut creation.

```
<RemoveFolder 
            Id="rem_folder" 
            Directory="APPLICATIONFOLDER" 
            On="uninstall"/>
<RemoveFile Id="rem_files"
            On="uninstall"
            Directory="APPLICATIONFOLDER"
            Name="*.*"/>
```

Comment: I have forget to say that you need to run your custom action after it is created:
`<InstallExecuteSequence> <Custom Action="RemoveAppFolder" Before="InstallFinalize">Installed</Custom> </InstallExecuteSequence>`